# Changing text color in CSS after event in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got this free template online [here](http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page151/hope-center#shout).

In this template, where you can see the banner "Make Donation", "Join Volunteer", "Help Children" have an active animation after which the picture on the right changes as soon as the concerned banner is active or selected.

My question is, how can I change the color of the text of "Make Donation" after it switches to the next one "Join Volunteer". In other words, now its in white color, I want to change it to red after it gets un-selected. As soon as it gets activated or selected again via the rotation set, it has to turn white in color again.

Here is the code for the banner slider animation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.slider')._TMS({
            preset: 'zabor',
            easing: 'easeOutQuad',
            duration: 800,
            pagination: true,
            banners: true,
            waitBannerAnimation: false,
            slideshow: 3000,
            bannerShow: function (banner) {
                banner.css({
                    right: '-700px'
                }).stop().animate({
                    right: '0'
                }, 600, 'easeOutExpo')
            },
            bannerHide: function (banner) {
                banner.stop().animate({
                    right: '-700'
                }, 600, 'easeOutExpo')
            }
        })
        $('.pagination li').hover(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
                $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
                    backgroundPosition: '0 0'
                }, 600, 'easeOutExpo', function () {
                    $(this).parent().css({
                        backgroundPosition: '-20px 0'
                    })
                });
            }
        }, function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
                $(this).css({
                    backgroundPosition: '0 0'
                }).find('a').stop().animate({
                    backgroundPosition: '-250px 0'
                }, 600, 'easeOutExpo');
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

The text concerned:

```
<ul class="pagination">
          <li id="banner1"><a href="#">Make<span>Donation</span></a></li>
          <li id="banner2"><a href="#">Join<span>Volunteer</span></a></li>
          <li id="banner3"><a href="#">Help<span>Children</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

In Style.css

```
.pagination {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:3
}
.pagination li {
    width:250px;
    height:155px
}
/*Change text for first top word*/

.pagination a {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:29px 0 0 33px;
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    font-weight:300;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    height:126px
}

/*Change text for first second word, spacing between first and second word */
.pagination a span {
    display:block;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    margin-top:-7px;
    letter-spacing:0
}

/*Boxes' colors*/

#banner1 a {
    background:url(../images/banner1_active.png) -250px 0 no-repeat;

        }


#banner2 a {
    background:url(../images/banner1_active.png) -250px 0 no-repeat;
}


#banner3 a {
    background:url(../images/banner1_active.png) -250px 0 no-repeat
    }


    .pagination #banner1:hover, .pagination #banner1.current, 
.pagination #banner2:hover, .pagination #banner2.current, 
.pagination #banner3:hover, .pagination #banner3.current,
 #banner1 a:hover, .pagination #banner1 a:after
     {
       color:red;
     }
```

The hover event,just changes the color to red only when I hover the cursor over and then it returns back. I need to change the text into red once the banner concerned gets activated by the `jquery` script. It seems that there is no linkage between the text and the script. I am eager to make the text change its property as a response from the rotation engaged by the script. Hope things are much more clearer now.

Comment: so, uh, what have you tried?

Comment: Post your markup and script/code.

Comment: does `.pagination .current { color:red;}` work?

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
.pagination .current a, .pagination a:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

should give you what you need.

EDIT:

don't use

```
.pagination #banner1:hover, .pagination #banner1.current, 
.pagination #banner2:hover, .pagination #banner2.current, 
.pagination #banner3:hover, .pagination #banner3.current,
 #banner1 a:hover, .pagination #banner1 a:after
 {
   color:red;
 }
```

Comment: It worked but it remains red rather than going back to white unless I hover over it. I tried removing the `hover` event with no luck.

Comment: I'm confused. When do you want it to be red?

Comment: Once `banner1` is activated, the text should be `red`. After moving to `banner2` the text of `banner1` should return back to white as normal without having to hover over it or renew the cycle.

Comment: by activated, you mean clicked on and/or when the script moves to that slide right?

Comment: clicked on and slide right. Its like when the rotation turn reaches `banner1` i.e `Make Donation` should change into `red`. Once the rotation moves to `banner2` turn, `Make Donation` Should go back white and `Join Volunteer` should turn red. No `hover` event is involved. What is happening now is that when I click on `Make donation` it remains `red` it doesn't go back `white`